# Templated placement new - calling destructor

Tags: c++, gcc, destructor, new-operator, placement-new

I'm creating my own vector implementation, using a template and placement new.

(If you're wondering why I'm creating a vector implementation, when the C++ library has one already, it's because I've got my own `mmap`-based memory allocator underneath it that I need for other reasons.)

The following code is just a contrived example - the actual memory buffer that my vector implementation works with is supplied from my memory allocator, but here I've just made a "char *pBuffer" to represent it, but there would be an underlying "Buffer" class that actually deals with allocation / deallocation / reallocation - to focus on just the essence of the problem I'm having:

```
template <typename Type> class Vector
{
    private:
        char *          pBuffer;

    public:
        Vector()
        {
            pBuffer = new char[sizeof(Type) * 100];
        }
        
        Type *create(int index)
        {
            Type *ptr = reinterpret_cast<Type *>(pBuffer);
                
            Type *item = new (&ptr[index]) Type();
            
            return item;
        }
        
        void remove(int index)
        {
            Type *ptr = reinterpret_cast<Type *>(pBuffer);
            
            Type *item = &ptr[index];
            
            item->~Type();
        }
        
        ~Vector()
        {
            delete pBuffer;
        }        
}
```

When I run this code through a debugger, though, it just skips over "item.~Type();" as if it's not there (single stepping just jumps straight over it), and the destructor is not called.

It's as if the compiler (GCC 7.5) is treating it as a null statement, ignoring it and not even compiling it in. As single stepping in GDB runs as if the call to the destructor is not even there. And no destructor is being called.

As I'm using placement new - to map this vector on top of some `mmap` allocated memory handled by another class - then I need to be able to call `Type`'s destructor to ensure everything is deallocated and cleaned up properly.

If I invoke the template with:

```
Vector<Track> tracks;
```

Then the destructor that needs to be called is really named "~Track()" and not "~Type()", but because it's a template and placement new is used, I need to call the destructor of whatever Type is supplied to the template to deconstruct the Type properly. But surely the template syntax automatically sees "~Type()" as "the destructor of the Type supplied to the template" and renames it accordingly?

Is there some kind of syntax I've not included to let the compiler know that, no, really, you must call the destructor and you can't ignore it or optimise it out?

Edit: fixed silly mistakes in code example.

Comment: Is `Track` non-trivial ?

Comment: `Type &item = &ptr[index]` shouldn't compile (unless `Type` has some unusual constructor). The type of `&ptr[index]` is `Type*`. Also, what's `Buffer` and how, if at all, is it related to `Vector`? It appears that the code you've shown is not the code you are actually compiling. For further assistance, prepare a [mcve].

Comment: ``Track`` is very non-trivial. Or, more precisely, I need this to work equally well, whether it's ``Vector<int>`` or ``Vector<VeryComplexClass>`` , as I'm going to be using this for a whole host of different types.

Comment: No, the code I've supplied, as I stated in the question, is not the code I'm compiling, as that's massive and most of it not relevant to the question. But you're right that the ``Buffer`` thing was a confused mistake on my part and I've edited the question to fix that now.

Comment: Please add also a small `main()` function to see how you use this template class, then we could test is as well. One problem I see is that it should be `delete[] pBuffer`, since it uses `new[]` in the constructor.